# python doit - how to echo the shell commands executed?

Tags: doit

The action of my task is a shell command. Is there an option in doit to display the actual shell command executed?

The reason I want this feature is that the shell command is dynamically created by python expression, so I want to see the actual command to help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

By default the task name is displayed, this can be changed with the [title](https://pydoit.org/tasks.html#title) property.

doit distribution includes the helper function [title_with_actions](https://pydoit.org/tools.html#title-with-actions-title) that does exactly what you are looking for.

```
from doit.tools import title_with_actions

def task_with_details():
    return {'actions': ['echo abc 123'],
            'title': title_with_actions}
```

Comment: Thanks @schettino72.  What you suggest defenitly works, but I'm thinking more of a command line option instead of modifying the file itself. Do you know whether there is such a command line option?

Comment: Currently not possible, but it would be a nice addition to `info` command. Please create an issue on github. It should be trivial to add this feature.

Comment: Created. https://github.com/pydoit/doit/issues/335. Did not realize you are the main contributor of the pacakge. Nice work!